# Extend Google Spreadsheets UI with a Google Web App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I created a script for Google Spreadsheets, this script just adds a new menu item as described here [Custom Menu Items in a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_extensions#menus). Then I deploy this script as a Web App and I want all users who install the app to be able to see the new menu item. And I'm stuck at this point.

As I understand, when you deploy a script as a Web App, onOpen functions looses it's meaning. So, inside doGet I create custom trigger for onOpen event, attach myOnOpen handler to it and inside myOnOpen I add a menu item, but the item doesn't show up.

Here's my code:

```
function doGet() {
    var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("new sheet");
    var newId = newSheet.getId();
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('newId', newId); 

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("myOnOpen")
        .forSpreadsheet(newId)
        .onOpen()
        .create();
};

function myOnOpen() {
    var newId = ScriptProperties.getProperty('newId');
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newId);

    var entries = [ { name : "Show bingo", functionName : "Bingo" } ];
    sheet.addMenu("My Menu", entries);
};

function Bingo() {
    Browser.msgBox("Bingo!");
};
```

So, when a user who installed the app opens "new sheet" spreadsheet, he doesn't see the "My Menu". What am I doing wrong here? Why the menu item doesn't show up? At the end of the day I want to create a Web App which extends Google Spreadsheets UI with additional menus and dialogs.

Any advice is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I can't figure out how the function Bingo can end up in the new spreadsheet 's script... neither can I for the 'myonopen' function... how do you imagine this process?  My opinion is that this is simply not possible... why not create a template with the script already included and after that create the trigger?  Could you clarify please? I'm really curious...

Comment: @Sergeinsas When a user executes the app, a custom trigger gets created in his GDrive. The trigger is attached to a particular spreadsheet in user's GDrive. Every time a user opens this spreadsheet, myOnOpen gets called. It works, I created test account, installed my app, opened "new sheet", myOnOpen was invoked. I can even modify the spreadsheet to some extent from within myOnOpen function (e.g. `sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 200)`), but I can't create custom menus there. Template doesn't work for me, I want users to upload their .xls files, and I want to add custom UI for editing these files.

Comment: How did you test that the myonOpen did run when a user opened the SS ? And how could Bingo work ? it has no link with the spreadsheet ... That doesn't correspond to the "script and container" definition.

Comment: @Sergeinsas I used `MailApp.sendEmail()`. myOnOpen is supposed to create a menu item, when the item is clicked, Bingo is invoked.

Comment: What you explain about users uploading their .xls files is not the same situation as creating new files like in your test... templates would also work, just use a script to copy the xls imported data (in a google ss) into a copy of the template and you're all set, the template copy will have a script attached and you can add the triggers just the way you do it now...

Comment: Thanks for the explanations ;-) I'm still wondering how this can work but I'll stop questioning you... good luck

Comment: @Sergeinsas This might work if copying data from .xls to a template isn't a tedious process. Can I do it with a couple of simple API calls? Could you please point me to some documentation on this?

Comment: It is quite straightforward ; use [sheet.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet#copyTo) using the xls import ss as source and the template copy as destination, do that for each sheet in a loop and that's all.

Comment: @Sergeinsas Thank you Serge, it works. This solution may have it's own drawbacks though, we'll see...

Comment: glad it helped, this was a looooong comment, apologies to sto ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy the script as a web app, users of the web app will only see content you "return" from the doGet function. You can create content using [UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp) or [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service) and return this content to be rendered in a browser. Your new menu items are attached to a spreadsheet, so they can only be displayed when the user goes to the spreadsheet itself (activating the onOpen trigger, etc).

Comment: In my scenario the following happens: user installs the app, after that user opens newly created "new sheet" in his GDrive, myOnOpen function runs, but the menu doesn't get added.